# Linux debian 8, unable to get some characters working

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, 64-bit, character-encoding

I'm using Debian8 64bit.

Today something weird happened..

I don't know why or how, but some characters doesn't work anymore.

I'm unable to make some special characters (example: @ and | ) I need them!

This happened today. They worked yesterday :I

Any tips?

I have tried dpkg-reconfigure locales and dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration, but no success.

(Those special characters works in Windows, but I don't want to use it)

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the default us keymap:

```
setxkbmap us
```

shift+2 = @

Comment: I'm using Finnish keyboard layout. I need shift + numbers for shifting irssi windows. @ was ctrl+alt and 2. Not working anymore

Comment: then `setxkbmap fi`

Comment: One moment, I'll try it

Comment: Didn't work. I booted also.

Comment: For example, if I press ctrl + alt and < |> button, it prints my older command from .bash_history. Yesterday it worked correctly (printing pipesymbol: | )

Comment: see /var/log/dpkg.log what packages were updated.

Comment: I didn't find any clue there. :(

Comment: I changed default button to Win button. Now win button + 2 (for @) example. I don't like this setup. Original (ctrl + alt and 2 or alt gr + 2) was better, but I really don't know how to switch that original configuration back.